# JavaFX: get target row index in TableView on keypressed event

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code:

```
public class JavaFxApplication extends Application{

    public class Article{

        private ObjectProperty<Integer> id;

        private StringProperty title;

        public Article(ObjectProperty<Integer> id, StringProperty title) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public ObjectProperty<Integer> getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public StringProperty getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Article> articles=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i=0;i<200;i++){
            articles.add(new Article(new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(i), new SimpleStringProperty("title_"+i)));
        }
        TableView<Article> tableView=new TableView(articles);
        TableColumn<Article,Integer> idColumn=new TableColumn("ID");
        idColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn‌​(new IntegerStringConverter()));
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(data->data.getValue().getId());
        tableView.getColumns().add(idColumn);

        TableColumn<Article,String> titleColumn=new TableColumn("Title");
        titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(data->data.getValue().getTitle());
        tableView.getColumns().add(titleColumn);

        tableView.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent t)-> {
            KeyCode key=t.getCode();
            if (key==KeyCode.PAGE_DOWN){
                int pos=tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println("INDEX:"+pos);
            }
        });

        VBox vbox=new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(tableView);
        Scene scene=new Scene(vbox, 200, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

After running of this application I select the first row (with id=0) and press page down key. And I want to get the index of the row to which the focus arrives but not the index of the row the focus leaves. But in my example the application output is `INDEX:0`. How to get the target row index?

Comment: How about just add listener for `selectedIndexProperty` property of selection model and save pressed key in instance variable?

Comment: @Maxim Dobryakov Thank you for your comment. But could you show what you mean on example?

Comment: `tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((observable, oldIndex, newIndex) -> { /* your code here */ });` where `newIndex` index or selected item.

Comment: @Maxim Dobryakov You change the logic. I need onkeypressed event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler is getting invoked before the built-in event handler that processes the "page down" action.

Use a `KEY_RELEASED` handler instead:

```
tableView.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent t)-> {
    KeyCode key=t.getCode();
    if (key==KeyCode.PAGE_DOWN){
        int pos=tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("INDEX:"+pos);
    }
});
```